# Binary Operations and Inverse elements in groups and functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, binary-operations

> Suppose we have group $G$ in relation to binary operation $*$ and $a\in G$ and function $f$ from $G$ to $G$ ($f:G\to G$), and for each $x\in G$ $f(x)=a^{-1} * x * a$.
>
> Prove that if $b,c\in G$ are inverse elements to each other, then $f(b)$ and $f(c)$ are inverse elements to each other as well.

My way of answer:
$b$ and $c$ are inverse elements, meaning that $f(b)=a^{-1} * b * a$ is the inverse of $f(c)=a^{-1} * c * a$, but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate $f(b)^{-1}$ by folowing the group laws:  \begin{align}f(b)^{-1}&= (a^{-1}ba)^{-1} \\&= a^{-1}b^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1} \\&=a^{-1}ca \\&= f(c)\end{align}

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. Just a quick question, Are you experienced in word and could you please tell me how to do these "=" on each line just like you did there?

Comment: Start with  \begin{align}

Comment: and then write f(b)^{-1}&= (a^{-1}ba)^{-1} \\&= a^{-1}b^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1} \\&=a^{-1}ca \\&= f(c)

Comment: and end with  \end{align}

Comment: It's LaTeX right?

Comment: Yes ..............

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\begin{align}
f(b)f(c)&=(a^{-1}ba)(a^{-1}ca)\\
&=a^{-1}b(aa^{-1})ca\\
&=a^{-1}(bc)a\\
&=a^{-1}ea\\
&=e,
\end{align}$$

which implies $f(b)=f(c)^{-1}$ by [uniqueness of inverses](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_in_Group_is_Unique).